# Pandas Python Data Frame: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

[image]I want to do save the scrape data in CSV . so I decided to use Pandas as I want to display the data in data frame. but I got an error in locating id of the element. I don't know whether my way of coding is wrong or there must be something else that I need to add in the coding.  btw,

> mainli_waninfo  #is for status tab

> subli_voipmaintain #is for VoipInfo tab

this is my coding

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
#import requests
import time 
#import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame

passwordStr = '***'
usernameStr='***
chrome_path = r'C:\Users\wana isa\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\geckodriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\wana isa\geckodriver-v0.26.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get(('http://******'))

wait = WebDriverWait(browser,10)


# wait for transition then continue to fill items
#time.sleep(2)
password = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'txt_Password')))
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'txt_Username')))
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

signInButton = browser.find_element_by_id('button')
signInButton.click()
browser.get(('****'))


MainTab=browser.find_element_by_name('mainli_waninfo').click()
SubTab=browser.find_element_by_name('subli_voipmaintain').click()
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('frameContent'))

html=browser.page_source
soup=bs(html,'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify()



#for Opticalinfo
time.sleep(6)

print('[VOIP INFORMATION]')#ONT INFORMATION
v1_id=['tdVoipInfo_0_0','tdVoipInfo_0_1','tdVoipInfo_0_2','tdVoipInfo_0_3','tdVoipInfo_0_4','tdVoipInfo_0_5','tdVoipInfo_0_6','tdVoipInfo_0_7']
v2_id=['tdVoipInfo_1_0','tdVoipInfo_1_1','tdVoipInfo_1_2','tdVoipInfo_1_3','tdVoipInfo_1_4','tdVoipInfo_1_5','tdVoipInfo_1_6','tdVoipInfo_1_7']

elemntValu= browser.find_element_by_id(v1_id).text
elemntValue= browser.find_element_by_id(v2_id).text
time.sleep(6)

C = {'no': ['tdVoipInfo_0_0','tdVoipInfo_1_0'],
        'Url': ['tdVoipInfo_0_1', 'tdVoipInfo_1_1'],
        'User Name(Phone Number)': ['tdVoipInfo_0_2', 'tdVoipInfo_1_2'],
        'Associated POTS Port': ['tdVoipInfo_0_3', 'tdVoipInfo_1_3'],
        'User Status': ['tdVoipInfo_0_4', 'tdVoipInfo_1_4'],
        'Call Status': ['tdVoipInfo_0_5', 'tdVoipInfo_1_5'],
        'Registry Error': ['tdVoipInfo_0_6', 'tdVoipInfo_1_6'],
        'Error Code': ['tdVoipInfo_0_7','tdVoipInfo_1_7'],
     
    }
df = DataFrame(C, columns= ['no', 'Url', 'User Name(Phone Number)', 'Associated POTS Port','User Status','Call Status','Registry Error','Error Code'])
export_csv = df.to_csv (r'C:\pandaresult.csv', index = None, header=True) # here you have to write path, where result file will be stored
print (df)


browser.close()
```

this is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-afe11729bf5e> in <module>
     54 v2_id=(['tdVoipInfo_1_0','tdVoipInfo_1_1','tdVoipInfo_1_2','tdVoipInfo_1_3','tdVoipInfo_1_4','tdVoipInfo_1_5','tdVoipInfo_1_6','tdVoipInfo_1_7'])
     55 
---> 56 browser.find_element_by_id(v1_id)
     57 browser.find_element_by_id(v2_id)
     58 time.sleep(6)

D:\waa\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_id(self, id_)
    358             element = driver.find_element_by_id('foo')
    359         """
--> 360         return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
    361 
    362     def find_elements_by_id(self, id_):

D:\waa\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
--> 978             'value': value})['value']
    979 
    980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

D:\waa\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

D:\waa\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="['tdVoipInfo_0_0', 'tdVoipInfo_0_1', 'tdVoipInfo_0_2', 'tdVoipInfo_0_3', 'tdVoipInfo_0_4', 'tdVoipInfo_0_5', 'tdVoipInfo_0_6', 'tdVoipInfo_0_7']"]
```

Comment: `Unable to locate element` probably suggests your `EC.presence_of_element_located` is unable to locate the element you want - check if the website uses the names you have used.

Comment: what do u mean by "check if the website uses the names you have used"? because the id has existed in the website. i take the id directly from inspect element.

Comment: You want to find multiple elements - one of them is `mainli_waninfo` - is that the id that the website uses? You have to inspect the `html` and see if that's the case. Also, on which line you are getting the error - that would point towards which element is to blame!

Comment: i updated the question. mainli_waninfor is id for status tab. i need to scrap the table and save it into csv file

Comment: You should add complete stacktrace of your error - which mentions on which line you got the error! (and I used mainli... as an example - that might not the element that's giving you the error)

Comment: i already repost the question.

Comment: Check if the `id` attribute matches the value `v1_id`. Use inspect to check. Maybe its on a different class or div. Take a screenshot of the webpage while inspecting the element then only we can able to help. The reason why `NoSuchElementException` is raised only because no element has a matching `id` attribute that you have defined. So check again if it matches.

Answer (score 0):

You see this seems to be the error : `elemntValu= browser.find_element_by_id(v1_id).text`

`find_element...` expects a string as argument like this : `driver.find_element_by_id('Email')` and you are passing off a whole list.

Try out :

```
v1_id_values = {}

for i in v1_id:
   v1_id_values[i] = browser.find_element_by_id(i).text

print(v1_id_values['tdVoipInfo_0_0'])
```

You have to do the same for the other list (`v2...`) as well.

**Although** I see you tried to store values in `elementValue` and then never accessed them after that. You would want to look into that as well. In the example I gave to access the value of `tdVoipInfo_0_0` you have to do `v1_id_values['tdVoipInfo_0_0'])` and so on.

Comment: do u mean i need to   do this print(v1_id_values['tdVoipInfo_0_0']) to every id? like print(v1_id_values['tdVoipInfo_0_1']), print(v1_id_values['tdVoipInfo_0_2']) and so on...? im sorry im so new in this python thingssss :')

Comment: WHat do you want here : `'no': ['tdVoipInfo_0_0','tdVoipInfo_1_0']` - I presume you want to add the values you scarped in the `no` key in your `dictionary C`?

then you need : `'no':[v1_id_values['tdVoipInfo_0_0'],v1_id_values['tdVoipInfo_1_0']]`